# Flutter - Firebase_messaging migrating from v7 to v11 - onMessage not being called

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, push-notification

I need some help in migrating my project.
Basically project is a bit old now, its running for almost 3 years and until now it was built with `flutter 1.22.6`. Now i am trying to migrate it to `v2.10.3` and migration is almost done. Last not working piece is iOS Push Notifications.

Old version is running on `firebase_messaging v.7.0.3` and it's working just fine.
Upgrading flutter demands version `9.0.0` or higher.

I've done basic code migration and Android is OK, but on iOS my `onMessage` handler is never being called.
Push is being delivered and notification is being displayed correctly when app is in background. But when its in foreground, or i will click that notification, app comes into the foreground, but callbacks are not being triggered.

The only thing i see in logs is error like:
`nw_endpoint_handler_set_adaptive_read_handler [C6.1 216.58.212.42:443 ready channel-flow (satisfied (Path is satisfied), viable, interface: en0, ipv4, dns)] unregister notification for read_timeout failed`

OFC i've looked through most of topics on stack and other places, but none of these solutions worked for me.
I'm not using any other plugins, such as `flutter_local_notifications` or similar, which could cause faults.

Most important pieces of code:

### flutter doctor

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 2.10.3, on macOS 11.6 20G165 darwin-x64, locale
    pl-PL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version
    33.0.0-rc3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.67.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

### pubspec.yaml

```
  firebase_core: 1.16.0
  firebase_messaging: 11.3.0
  google_ml_kit: 0.7.3
```

### AppDelegate.swift

```
override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        disableCache();
        FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        self.SetupPushNotification(application: application)
    
    func SetupPushNotification(application: UIApplication) -> () {
        if #available(iOS 10, *){ UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert,.sound,.badge])
        {(granted,error) in
            if granted{
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                }
            } else {
                print("User Notification permission denied: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "error")")
            }
        }
        }
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        NotificationDeviceToken.sharedInstance.setToken(token: tokenString(deviceToken))
     }

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        print(userInfo)
     }

     func tokenString(_ deviceToken:Data) -> String{
         let bytes = [UInt8](deviceToken)
         var token = ""
         for byte in bytes{
             token += String(format: "%02x",byte)
         }
         return token 
     }
```

### main.dart

```
void startApp(AppConfig config) async {
  // add this, and it should be the first line in main method
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  ...
}
```

### app.dart

```
  void init(BuildContext context, AppCubit cubit,
      SubscriptionManager subscriptionManager) {
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((map) {
      _log.debug('onMessage: ${map.data}');
      final push = Push(map.data, PushType.onMessage);
      _streamController.add(push);
      return Future<bool>.value(true);
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((map) {
      _log.debug('onMessageOpenedApp: ${map.data}');
      _startAppFromPush = true;
      final push = Push(map.data, PushType.onLaunch);
      _streamController.add(push);
      return Future<bool>.value(true);
    });
  }
```

### Info.plist

```
...
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled<key/>
<false/>
...
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found solutions.

I've found an issue opened in github flutterfire project.
One of topics was very similar to my trouble.
https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/4300

The thing is that every push sent from FCM gets additional field in payload called `gcm.message_id`.
Notifications from APNS do not get this field.

Plugin `firebase_messaging` starting from version 9 up to now is validating this field and if push does not contain it, callbacks `onMessage` and `onMessageOpenedApp` are not being triggered.

If You are facing similar trouble You have 2 options:

- add missing field in Your APNS message payload
- create Your own fork with firebase_messaging plugin and modify FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin in 2 places, where proper if statements are located.

I hope this will be useful to some of You. I've spent a lot of time researching this issue.